# Re-using database connection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, groovy

I have following `JavaAWS` class in **Groovy** (it is using Java AWS SDK), but now I don't know how to re-use database connection in stage1 and stage2.
Basically I'd like to use the same database connection everywhere and now I am not sure what is the way to achieve it.

My `ReplicateInstanceStatus` and `ReplicateMetricStatistics` classes are empty for the moment so I haven't pasted it there.

```
public class JavaAWS {

    Object database = null

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def obj = new JavaAWS()
        obj.run()
    }
    public JavaAWS() {
        database = new MongoClient()
    }

    public void run() {
        println "Running stage 1 ReplicateInstanceStatus"
        def stage1 = new ReplicateInstanceStatus()
        def ret1 = stage1.run()

        println "Running stage 2 ReplicateMetricStatistics"
        def stage2 = new ReplicateMetricStatistics()
        def ret2 = stage2.run()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a case that clearly calls for dependency injection. Instead of whatever the mechanism is that you're using to get the connection to your stage objects, which is probably some sort of roundabout global, just make them take the `MongoClient` as a constructor argument.

This is also a case where a singleton pattern seems like a Bad Idea. What would happen if someone wanted to run multiple of your jobs in parallel? A singleton is essentially a global variable, and only things that naturally only have one representation should be singletons; database connections don't fit.

Comment: MongoClient is a thread-safe connection pool, and the question was how to re-use the same connection pool. Will passing it over via constructor create additional connections?

Comment: @Andrew If you use it to, but that's the same object being reused in the question. Passing a `Mongo` would generally be even better (and make it easier to mock for testing).

Comment: It seems that it's working fine. It's not cloning that DB Object, so it's OK. However I can't see why the global enum is not better than passing the reference all the time, isn't that effectively the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Singleton is the solution and that "The enum way" is easiest approach:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_enum_way

Here is transcript:

> **The enum way**
>
> In the second edition of his book Effective Java, Joshua Bloch claims that "a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton"[8] for any Java that supports enums. The use of an enum is very easy to implement and has no drawbacks regarding serializable objects, which have to be circumvented in the other ways.
>
> ```
> public enum Singleton {
>     INSTANCE;
>     public void execute (String arg) {
>         // Perform operation here 
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The public method can be written to take any desired types of arguments; a single String argument is used here as an example.
>
> This approach implements the singleton by taking advantage of Java's guarantee that any enum value is instantiated only once in a Java program. Since Java enum values are globally accessible, so is the singleton, initialized lazily by the class loader. The drawback is that the enum type is somewhat inflexible.